# Not being able to send the whole email - smtp

Tags: python, smtp

```
sent_subject = "Warning"
sent_body = (
             "Hey"
             "For game ID: {} and game Name: {} \n\n you are going to die in {}sec"
             "\n\n"
             "Warning,\n"
             "Chixcy\n".format(game_id, game_name, secs))

smtp_server.sendmail(sender_add,receiver_add,sent_body)
```

The email which I am getting is `you are going to die in 30sec Warning Chixcy`

I want to get the whole body along with subject

Comment: Just make message a string only

Comment: what you have is a tuple of strings where you format the last

Comment: @mama, it's not a tuple. There are no commas. The code here uses string concatenation without operator (implicit string concatenation) which is used a lot when you want your multiline string to be indented in code without having the indents in the string itself. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because first few lines should be email headers. You also never use your subject anywhere - that could've been a hint.

Therefore we need to

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
message = MIMEText(sent_body, 'plain')
message["From"] = sender_add
message["To"] = receiver_add
message["Subject"] = sent_subject
```

Then when you're doing .sendmail, you have to:

```
smtp_server.sendmail(sender_add, receiver_add, message.as_string())
```

A note: There are also more convenient (more human-friendly) classes to deal with emails (e.g. [email.message.EmailMessage](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html#email.message.EmailMessage) introduced in Python 3.6), but as I've been mostly dealing with multipart emails since Python 3.4, pure MIME messages are my way.